# Remove event listener issue in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

```
const ControlPanel = ({ mainSectionRef }) => {
    const [canMove, setCanMove] = useState(false)
    const classes = useStyles();
    const toolbarRef = useRef();

    const onMouseMove = function (e) {
        const { x, y } = getMouseCoordinatesOnCanvas(e, mainSectionRef.current);
        toolbarRef.current.style.left = x +'px';
        toolbarRef.current.style.top = y + 'px';
    }

    const setCan = () => {
        setCanMove(!canMove)
    }

    if (mainSectionRef.current) {
        //issue is here!!!!
        mainSectionRef.current.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, true)
        if (canMove) {
            mainSectionRef.current.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, true)
        }
    }

    return (
        <Toolbar ref={toolbarRef}>
           <RadioButtonUncheckedIcon />
           <CropSquareIcon />
           <ArrowRightAltIcon />
           <CloseIcon />
           <DragIndicatorIcon style={{ backgroundColor: canMove ? "red" : "inherit" }} onClick={setCan}/>
        </Toolbar >
    );
}
export default ControlPanel;
```

I'm trying to remove the event listener whenever there is a state change in the component. `mainSectionref` is a parent `div` and the control panel is the child component. I'm trying to move the control panel in the `mainSection` `onClick` of a button. The event does get added but on state change, it doesn't seem to remove the event listener. Can I know what's going wrong?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
    function onMouseMove(e) {
        //Some code
    }
    if (mainSectionRef.current) {
        **mainSectionRef.current.onmousemove = null**;
        if (canMove) {
            mainSectionRef.current.onmousemove = e => onMouseMove(e);
        }
    }
}, [canMove])
```

---

The issue is resolved by using the key *onmousemove*. I still don't know why **removeEventListener** is not working in the above case.

Answer (score 1):

You should use useEffect hook from react and put your addEventListener and removeEventListener code inside useEffect as first argument. useEffect takes second argument as dependency it means on what values change useEffect should call . In your case you want to call useEffect when ever canMove changes.

```
  useEffect(() => {
   if (mainSectionRef.current) {
   mainSectionRef.current.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, true)
     if (canMove) {
     mainSectionRef.current.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, true)
    }
   }
  }, [canMove]);
```

also remember : `import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';`

Comment: Hey Zohaib, thanks for the response. I appreciate the enhancement. Unfortunately, the problem still exists. The **removeEventListener** seems to be not working for some reason. It would be great if somebody could identify the issue. Thanks, zohaib for the suggestion though.